# Reduce size from Whatsapp

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, whatsapp-messenger, internal-sd

Whatsapp backups take a lot of space. Is there any possible way to save more space without totally messing up Whatsapp?

Comment: I would imagine there isn't much you can do. If Whatsapp images/videos/media are stored on your device memory you could move/delete them. Even if you could move it to external sd the notifications wouldn't work on it. Otherwise you're looking at clearing caches regularly or a more extreme is to root and find a ROM with EXT support to mimic internal SD on the external SD.